# What does $0.1, $0.0, etc. mean in Swift?

Tags: swift

I saw a dictionary data, its value is like:

```
var myDict = ["name": "John",
              "age": 28]
```

I see a code like below:

```
myDict.flatMap {
           let a = $0.0
           let b = $0.1
           ...
 }
```

What does `$0.0` mean? What does `$0.1` mean? What is the difference between `$0` and `$0.1`?

Comment: Show the code where a and b variables are used.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`$0` is a shorthand name for first argument passed to closure. In this case, as you're mapping a `Dictionary`, that argument is a tuple - hence `$0.0` is a key, and `$0.1` is a value

For more info on shorthand argument names, see Swift documentation on [closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

Comment: For better readability you should use `$0.key` for the key and `$0.value` for the value.

Comment: Or `flatMap { (key, value) in ... }`

Comment: Also parentheses it is not needed `key, value in`

Comment: Why do you say argument is a tuple? Isn't tuple value comma separated e.g. `(3,4)`? Dictionary's mapping argument is colon separated e.g. ("name":"John"). Are you saying tuple could also be colon separated e.g. (3:4)?